# Websocket Connection for React Proxy inside Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, proxy

I have a simple React Front-end that uses a proxy Node.js server to fetch data over http and ws.
This runs completely fine on my local host.

When I run this within a docker container, the http calls still work, but the ws connection cannot be established.

If I expose my proxy server port with:

```
    ports:
  - 2999:2999
```

Also the ws connection starts to work. I ***do not want to expose*** the proxy server though.
I thought about running this entire setup in another docker container, but that would be the last option for me.

I thought setting:

```
ports:
  - "2999"
```

Would just make the internal port of the docker image available and solve my problem, but it does not.

How do I expose the port of the proxy to the react app, but not the outside network?
(both react app and proxy are in the same docker image)